# Python/Pandas/SKLearn - Writing to original JSON input

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm quite comfortable with working with Python, but I mostly used Pandas dataframes up until now. For a change, I'll have to work with JSON input now. I've found how I can load it into Python and Pandas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069876/working-with-json-nested-in-json-using-python-pandas), my question would be if it's possible to preserve the nested structure of the original input JSON file, while adding a new custom column to it? I'd like to compute a new column with some sklearn algorithms and add it to the original input file, while preserving the JSON file's structure (except for, of course, adding a new column).

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you are trying to append to a json item?

```
data = [ { 'a':'A', 'b':(2, 4), 'c':3.0 } ]
print 'DATA:', repr(data)
DATA: [{'a': 'A', 'c': 3.0, 'b': (2, 4)}]
```

Say you want to append f:var

```
data[0]['f'] = var
print 'JSON', json.dumps(data)
JSON:[{'a': 'A', 'c': 3.0, 'b': (2, 4), "f":2.4}]
```